# I am trying to make an APP that has a background music in it

Tags: java, android

I want it to pause the music when I press the home or back button and when I come back to the app I would like it to continue where it stopped. Don't mind the onClick function.

This is the code I have right now. When I press back button it stops the music and when I go back to the app the music starts from the begining. When I press the home button it stops the music and when I go back to the app, it doesnt even start the music from the begining.

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        r = new Random();

        pesnicka = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.thehampsterdance);
        pesnicka.start();
        pesnicka.setLooping(true);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int max = images.length - pocitadlo - 1;
                int min = 0;
                int nahoda = (int)(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
                imageView.setImageResource(images[nahoda]);
                pocitadlo++;
                for (int i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
                    if (i >= nahoda){
                        if (i < images.length - 1) {
                            obrazok[i] = images[i + 1];
                        }
                    } else{
                        obrazok[i] = images[i];
                    }
                }
                obrazok[images.length - 1] = images[nahoda];
                images = Arrays.copyOf(obrazok, images.length);
                if (pocitadlo == images.length){
                    pocitadlo = 0;
                }
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();        //  <<-------ENSURE onStop
        pesnicka.pause();
        pesnicka.reset();
        pesnicka.release();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        pesnicka.pause();
    }
```